# FOSS ModBus libraries/VCl?

Tags: modbus

I'm looking for FOSS (for commercial use) VCL components for Delphi or libraries for Visual Basic/C/C++/C# ... basically, just something to abstract the h/w for development, although a h/w simulator might be useful for testing.

Does anyone know what is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at MODBUS simulator [here](http://www.plcsimulator.org/Home). [This one](http://support-omron.fr/MultiwayE.php) is also worth a look. For Delphi components take a look [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphimodbus/), [here](http://mbserver.tripod.com/), and if you don't mind the nag screen [here](http://www.ozm.cz/ivobauer/modlink/).

Answer (score 2):

[JaMod](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/) is an open source Java implementation of the Modbus protocol. I've used it before to simulate a Modbus master device. I believe you could use it to simulate the slave device as well.